# Unity - audio files play badly on iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, audio, unity-game-engine

Suddenly all my sounds sound really weird on the iphone and ipad, but they still sound ok in the Editor.
On the devices they sound similar to if they were played through a bad telephone connection over speaker - or if they were recorded with poor quality. And again, this only happens on the iPhone and iPad devices, in Unity itself it's all fine.

Things I tried already:

- I have 3D sound disabled on the audio files
- on the AudioSource, I have Bypass Effects, ByPass Listener Effects and Bypass Reverb Zones all set to 'true'
- Doppler Level is set to 0

A while ago this was all good, and it may have happened when I updated to Unity 4.5.4 and XCode 6.0.1.
But I can't say that for sure.

Any ideas what that could be?

Answer (score 0):

found it!
The problem was that in the Audio Settings 'Volume' was set 100 for some strange reason.

So - on the MAC the volume was set to small that's why it played ok - but on the iPhone it tried playing the loud sound so the speakers just went mad....